# How make null MovieClip in function?

Tags: actionscript-3

How make null MovieClip in function? I tried:

```
function one()
{
var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
two(mc);
}

function two(mcref:MovieClip)
{
mcref=null;
}
```

but unfortunately it does not work and "mc" isn't null after function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is scope chain issue. if you pass MovieClip to `two()` function. Actually passing a reference value not. so You can't access the reference object in function. valid the value or execute only within the function scope.

read a this: [AS3 Funciton](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html)

> Any time a function begins execution, a number of objects and
>   properties are created. First, a special object called an activation
>   object is created that stores the parameters and any local variables
>   or functions declared in the function body. You cannot access the
>   activation object directly, because it is an internal mechanism.
>   Second, a scope chain is created that contains an ordered list of
>   objects that Flash Player or Adobe AIR checks for identifier
>   declarations. Every function that executes has a scope chain that is
>   stored in an internal property. For a nested function, the scope chain
>   starts with its own activation object, followed by its parent
>   function’s activation object. The chain continues in this manner until
>   it reaches the global object. The global object is created when an
>   ActionScript program begins, and contains all global variables and
>   functions.

Comment: Just for clarity, both answers here are correct. This answer explains why the original code wasn't working. The answer below by @Vipul shows how to make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

It should work, try this :

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public var mc:MovieClip;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        mc = new MovieClip();
        trace("mc : " , mc);

        makeMovieClipNull();
        trace("mc 2: ", mc);
    }

    public function makeMovieClipNull():void
    {
        mc=null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work and "mc" isn't null after function, only "target".

Comment: It not that I wanted. I needed to make null of MovieClip in external function, but as told "bitmapdata.com" it's impossible.

Comment: @user2160453 - it's possible to do it in a function, however, you cannot pass the movie clip to the function. The function must be able to access the movie clip variable directly (like in this trivial example). Notice that in this example the movie clip is declared as a member variable and that it is public. Because it is a member variable, it means that  any function in this class can access the variable and set it to null. And because it is a public variable, functions in other classes can also access the variable and set it to null. I'll modify Vipul's answer slightly to show that.

Comment: I needed to make null of MovieClip in external function (in another class for example) and your fix isn't that I wanted.